# Can't see Site.Master

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, master-pages

I'm learning ASP.NET from a book and there's a page about creating a web form with master page. On the picture in a book, at the 'Select Master Page' window there are two options (Site.Master & Site.Mobile.Master), but I can't see either of those. I'm using the same version of Visual Studio (Community 2015)
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Make sure you create your project using the same template mentioned in the book. Did you check if the files exist in the folder

Comment: I'm pretty sure I used the same template as in the book

Comment: Did you check if the files exist?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a master page as `site1.master` then only you have to add content pages under that master

You can create any number of master pages